# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes on splash screen after broken upgrade from 13.10

Tags: upgrade, xorg, 14.04, xserver, do-release-upgrade

I'm using VirtualBox to run my ubuntu VM on Mac. I've decided to make a distro upgrade which was apparently a very big mistake...

During upgrading my Mac hung up and I had to make hard reset. After this, when I run my ubuntu VM I can see Ubuntu splash screen with orange dots progress bar. All dots are orange and then if freezes.

I managed to open root shell, and run:

```
apt-get -f install
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get update
```

So at least apt is working now and all software seems to be up to date.

But if I run:

```
startx
```

I get:

```
X: exec of /usr/bin/Xorg failed
xinit: giving up
xinint: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

When I try to run /usr/bin/Xorg manually I get:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/Xorg: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.